# Why can't I run "python manage.py startup APP_NAME" with django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a Django app, but it doesn't let me startup the app so I can bring it to the development server. I run `python manage.py startup APP_NAME`, where I expect the app to run. Instead, I get an error saying there is no such file or directory called manage.py. However, I have it open.

[image]

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: What's the working directory that you're invoking `python` from?

Comment: C:\Users\imung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe

Comment: `startup`? Probably `startapp`. That won't actually *run* the app, just create a default template to edit a new app. To run, use  the `runserver` subcommand instead.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need to ensure on your terminal  what is the directory  your project is located, by using command prompt "ls" if you are using Linux, or dir on Windows, then you need to activate your virtual environment using source virtual_env_name/bin/activate... then you can execute python manage.py

Answer (score -1):

You need to run:

```
python manage.py startapp APP_NAME
```

to create new app in django